# cursor does not align with text with Google Chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

With Google Docs on Google Chrome on Ubuntu I keep having to close the browser to try to fix the problem where the cursor does not line up with the text.  When that happens you cannot type, because the cursor is not positioned where you are typing.

[image: Google Docs on Chrome on Ubuntu]

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common bug in Google Docs.
They recommend you to change font and use ctrl+0 to reset zoom.

Both hints did not solve the problem for many users. I switched to firefox in this case.

So its google's turn to fix this.

Comment: People with poor vision like me need to be able to zoom in.  So it's a accessibility issue required by US law!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue & tried the various solutions mentioned here & in google support but it didn't work. It was a weirdly frustating issue.

1. I checked up with my various google accounts & it persisted, thus it ruled out the possiblility of clicking or pressing any such options via mouse or keyboard that may cause such behavior.
2. I checked various editors, local LibreOffice or Microsoft office I had & it is working fine. So my keyboards are working fine.
3. I checked with my other colleagues. Their drive is working perfectly so it's not a universal issue.
4. I checked with other browsers & it worked perfectly fine. So it was chrome related issue.
5. Now I checked the current version & when it was updated. It matched with issue experienced date.

In this way, I came to the conclusion it's a chrome version-related issue. Either you downgrade or wait for an update.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I had it started with one student with Google issues, by the end of the day I had heard from 10 students and colleagues. The cursor remains in one place, with no ability to copy and paste and text becoming scrambled. The only solution I have found is resetting the Chrome settings: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3296214?hl=en